# Show $[(P\Rightarrow Q)\land(Q\Rightarrow R)]\Rightarrow(P\Rightarrow R)$ is a tautology using a truth table.

Tags: logic

Show $[(P\Rightarrow Q)\land(Q\Rightarrow R)]\Rightarrow(P\Rightarrow R)$ is a tautology using a truth table.

I have constructed the following truth table, however, I must have made an error because there are two rows that do not actually match between the hypothesis and conclusion. Could someone point out where the problem is?

| $P$ | $Q$ | $R$ | $P\Rightarrow Q$ | $Q\Rightarrow R$ | $(P\Rightarrow Q)\land(Q\Rightarrow R)$ | $(P\Rightarrow R)$ | $[(P\Rightarrow Q)\land(Q\Rightarrow R)]\Rightarrow (P\Rightarrow R)$ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T | T | T | T | T | T | T | T |
| T | T | F | T | F | F | F | T |
| T | F | F | F | T | F | F | T |
| T | F | T | F | T | F | T | T |
| F | T | T | T | T | T | T | T |
| F | F | T | T | T | T | T | T |
| F | F | F | T | T | T | T | T |
| F | T | F | T | F | F | T | T |

The problem is with my fourth and last row. I where the entries in the last two columns do not align.

Comment: $F \Rightarrow T$ is valued as true.  So those rows are not misaligned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were not asked to show that $(P \implies Q) \land (Q \implies R)$ is equivalent to $P \implies R$. Rather, you were asked to show that $((P \implies Q) \land (Q \implies R)) \implies (P \implies R)$ is a tautology. So, you need to make a column for the proposition $((P \implies Q) \land (Q \implies R)) \implies (P \implies R)$ and verify that each entry in the column is `T`.